# Polynomial properties

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, divisor-sum

I am interested in finding out the name of the following polynomials (if already named) and additionaly any of their properties:

$$p_N(x) = \sum_{d|N}{x^{d+\frac{N}{d}}}$$

It is clear they will only have +2 values as coefficients and exceptionally a +1 one when N is a perfect square.
I also guessed they would be related to cyclotomic polynomial as their definition involve a Dirichlet convolution too, but no clear at all in which way it could be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think is mean that if $p_N(x)=\sum_{i}a_ix^i$, then for all $i$ we have $a_i\in\{0,1,2\}$. Moreover, $a_i=1$ is possible only if $N$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Thanks both for specifying. That was it. Also corrected original post in order to keep it clear.